# Add drawable and string resources into framework, then compile error

Tags: android, android-source

I added some drawable resources into directory `frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxx` and some string resources into `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/strings`.
Also I added the names of these resources into `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/symbols.xml`.

```
<java-symbol type="string" name="xxx1" /> 
<java-symbol type="string" name="xxx2" /> 
<java-symbol type="drawable" name="xxx3" />
<java-symbol type="drawable" name="xxx4" />
```

But why the android project can't make successfully?
This is the error:

```
You have tried to change Android framework-res resource ID. Please fix the errors listed above by 
restoring the changes.
```

I only added drawables into drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue? I am having the exact same one.

Comment: Hey, @Olaia ,did you solve this issue? I've got a solution.Add another res package and add all resources you need into this package.You can consult the framework res package for how to add res package.

Comment: Hey @T-Chen, yes, that's exactly how I managed to do it. I guess that's the way some manufacturers work with the AOSP but it's quite inconvenient and not easy to guess. But anyhow, thanks for your response!